Is there a way to place the prompt cursor at the bottom of the console?
In MSDOS, I wrote a prompt (%PROMPT%) that output a reverse color (white) line at the top of the console with information like MSDOS version and time/date. Then the prompt text ($P$G) and cursor moved to the bottom of the console.  Standard output color was Cyan while the prompt string itself was white.
I don't care about a "title" since all windows now have titles. I don't care about the color of the output. I do want the prompt to always appear at the bottom of the console (even after clearing the screen or whatever).
I tried this:
function prompt
{
    $windowHeigth = [Console]::WindowHeight
    $windowWidth  = [Console]::WindowWidth
    [Console]::SetCursorPosition(0, $windowHeigth-1)

    "PS $($ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($NestedPromptLevel + 1)) "
}

This does place the prompt at the bottom of the console, but when I clear the screen it reverts to the default style prompt location. I can't find out how to find the coordinate of the first row of the last line in the console.

After some experimentation this is what I came up with:
function prompt
{
    $rows = [Console]::WindowHeight
    $setCursorBottom = "`e[${rows};0H"
    "${setCursorBottom}PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) "
}


Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding what you want. You'll need to create a custom clear function that moves the prompt and then re-alias it to 'clear'. This will put the prompt back where you want it.
# Delete the built-in clear alias
del alias:clear -Force

# Custom Clearing Alias
function MyClearScreen {
    Clear-Host
    $windowHeigth = [Console]::WindowHeight
    $windowWidth  = [Console]::WindowWidth
    [Console]::SetCursorPosition(0, $windowHeigth-1)
}

# Set the new clear alias
Set-Alias -Name clear -Value MyClearScreen

